# Read data from RF 433

Tags: gpio, pi-3

I bought an RF sender and a receiver mode. The sender is connected to GPIO 6 and the receiver to GPIO 12.
At first I just want to test with the simplest of tarnsmission tests.
Here is my sender py code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Broadcom pin-numbering scheme
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT) # output rf
print("Testing RF out, Press CTRL+C to exit")

try:
     print("set GIOP high")
     GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(5)               
except KeyboardInterrupt: # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
   print("Keyboard interrupt")

except:
   print("some error") 

finally:
   print("clean up") 
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO
```

The code is just setting high the GPIO 6 and five seconds later quit.
The receiver (which I start before a start sending anything):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Broadcom pin-numbering scheme
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN) # input RF

print("Starting to read RF input, CTRL+C to exit")

try:
     while 1:
          if GPIO.input(12):
             print("Something from GPIO 12")  
except KeyboardInterrupt: # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
   print("Keyboard interrupt")

except:
   print("some error") 

finally:
   print("clean up") 
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO
```

Unfortunately I don't get anything from GPIO 12. I am a newbie to RF communication. What do I have to do the get something. The code is very terse and at this point I just want to test I actually get something.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your logic or your code (although I haven't tried running the code).

Double check you are using the correct GPIO.  GPIO 6/12 are on pins 31/32 of the 40 pin expansion header.

You could test the code receive logic with my [pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html) utility (part of the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) suite).

```
sudo pigpiod
pigs w 12 0
pigs w 12 1
```

Another diagnostic tool to consider is [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) which will let you visualise GPIO level changes.

Comment: Thank you. When running "pigs w 12 1" my python rfin,py start showing "Something from GPIO 12" as expected.
However my rfout.py does not achieve that, Thank you. I'll figure it out.

Comment: I am getting a bit of noise - not much - but every 3-5 secs a few clicks on the reader side.
Would a pull up/pull down resistor help? If so what sort (ohm) I should use?

Comment: No, not really.  You can power the transmitter from 5V but the receiver needs to be powered from 3.3V (unless you use a voltage divider on the receive pin).  Do you have aerials attached to the receiver and transmitter?  Perhaps edit your question to add a photo of your kit.

Comment: The reader and transmitetr are rated to work 3v-12v so I've put it to use 3.3V. Aerials (abou 17.5 cm) have been soldered to both. I have a cordless mouse nearby.

Comment: @user1231247 Perhaps the auto level detection is kicking in and rejecting a level signal.  Try sending a PWM signal on the transmitter or send some codes using http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py or http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D

Comment: I am a newbie to RF communications. What is auto level detection?

Comment: I'm not the person to try to explain.  Have a look at http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/frequently-asked-questions/201551981Detector_FAQ.pdf